# Eager load filter based on child records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public bool Property { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

How would you eager load the parent class with its child class but filter based on a child class field? For example how would I select `Parent` records based on whether `Child.Property` was `true`? But I would also like to load all the Children of the Parent regardless if their Property property was set to `true`.

My attempt:

```
_context.Parents.Include(x => x.Children.Where(x => x.Property == true)).ToListAsync();
```

This seems to load every parent record, but it loads all the children (regardless of whether their Property property is set to true) of Parents that have a Child with Property property set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
_context.Parents
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(c => c.Property))
    .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Wizard status; confirmed.

thanks br0